# Copying databricks workflows from one environment to another using terraform

Tags: terraform, databricks, azure-databricks

I am currently trying to take workflows from one databricks environment to another using terraform.

I have two databricks providers setup to access each databricks environment

I am using a data source lookup to get my jobs

```
variable "jobs" {
    type = list
    default = ["job1","job2"]
}

data "databricks_job" "jobs" {
  for_each = toset(var.jobs)
  job_name = each.key
}

output "x" {
    value = data.databricks_job.jobs
}
```

in the above block I get the data for jobs with names "job1" and "job2"

Now I am trying to create these jobs in another databricks environment, so I try the following.

```
resource "databricks_job" "jobs" {
  #provider for second db env
  provider = databricks.db2
  for_each = data.databricks_job.jobs
  
  name = each.value.job_name
}
```

This will create the jobs with just the names, since I have no added any tasks.

Here is where I am stuck.

I am trying to create tasks in these new jobs.  job1 has 2 tasks, and job2 has 1 task.  So I need to iterate a second time in the resource block to create multiple tasks.

I am able to get the tasks for job 1 by using the above data look block like this:

```
data.databricks_job.jobs["job1"].job_settings[0].settings[0].task
```

I think what I need is in my resource block I need to iterate over the list of tasks for each job and set them.  I am not sure how to do this with a nested for_each.

I am also not sure if I can create multiple tasks by using a foreach in the resource block.

Any suggestions?  Am I approaching this problem correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the tasks using the `dynamic` keyword, for example:

```
variable "jobs" {
    type = list
    default = ["job1","job2"]
}

data "databricks_job" "jobs" {
  for_each = toset(var.jobs)
  job_name = each.key
}

resource "databricks_job" "jobs" {
  provider = databricks.db2
  for_each = data.databricks_job.jobs

  name = each.value.job_name

  dynamic "task" {
    for_each = [for task in each.value.settings.tasks : task if task.spark_jar_task != null]

    content {
      task_key = each.value.task_key

      new_cluster {
        num_workers   = 1
        spark_version = data.databricks_spark_version.latest.id
        node_type_id  = data.databricks_node_type.smallest.id
      }

      spark_jar_task {
        main_class_name = each.value.main_class_name
      }
    }
  }

  dynamic "task" {
    for_each = [for task in each.value.settings.tasks : task if task.notebook_task != null]

    content {
      task_key = each.value.task_key

      job_cluster_key = each.value.job_cluster_key

      notebook_task {
        notebook_path = each.value.notebook_path
      }
    }
  }

  dynamic "task" {
    for_each = [for task in each.value.settings.tasks : task if task.pipeline_task != null]

    content {
      task_key = each.value.task_key

      pipeline_task {
        pipeline_id = each.value.pipeline_id
      }
    }
  }
}
```